# How to suppress alert when refreshing Essbase/SmartView Table?

Tags: vba, oracle, essbase

[image]

I'm trying to get past this alert. Using **DisplayAlerts=False** does not work.

Comment: Well it's an error message, not an alert. You have to click on it.

Comment: What's the rest of your code?

Comment: @BigBen The rest of the code is related to the function for HypExecuteMenu to refresh an essbase table in excel.

Comment: @braX How do I say 'Yes' in VBA? I don't want to prompt the user for this.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the Essbase/SmartView API allows for a way around this.

Comment: Then fix the code that is causing the error.

Comment: @BigBen There is supposed to be a function HypSetGlobalOption(5, 3) that will not display any error messages but it doesn't work

Comment: I'd have to test it... maybe tomorrow. I've gotten the same error message before. What version of SmartView?